# Display object array in react

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, reactjs, mongodb

**New to React and Node and was trying out fetching data into a functional component by following some tutorials.

I managed to create the server and establish the DB connection and fetch the data in react by following the tuts, but when I went ahead to use the data by outputting it , I did not get any results.

I have attached the screenshot of the console , which shows that my state ,exercises , has the data.
Can anyone please help me by guiding me where I am wrong.Maybe it is an object array and I need to convert it to something else?**

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const Navbar = () => {
const [exercises, setCount] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    axios
        .get('http://localhost:5000/exercises/')
        .then(response => {
            setCount([...exercises, response.data]);  
                   })
}, []);

console.log({exercises});

var formatted = exercises.map((item) => {
return(
 <div key="1">
   <p>{item.username}</p>
   <p>{item.duratiom}</p>
   </div>
)
});

 return(
 <div>
 {formatted}
 </div>
) ;

}
export default Navbar;[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

fetch call from the server

```
router.route('/').get((req,res) => {
Exercise.find()
    .then(exercises => res.json(exercises))
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error:'+err));
});
```

[image]

Comment: I believe the structure is still rendered (since you are not getting any errors), but the ```username``` and ```duration``` are not present in the ```item``` when you map through the exercises. In your ```excercise.map```, before you return, can you ```console.log(item)```?

Comment: @szczocik I added this  `console.log("testing"+item.username);` and in the console it came out as testingundefined ..

Comment: Try not giving every item the same key; use `key={item._id}` instead.

Comment: I think i am missing something really basic here.But that tends to happen while learning a new language

Comment: Yeah, the structure of the exercises data is not what you are expecting - the username does not exist. Can you log ```item``` to see what the data structure is?

Comment: @ChrisG that will give me `Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.` since item.id will be undefined :(

Comment: `item._id`, not `item.id`; also you have `.duratiom` instead of `.duration`, but the username at least does appear for me: https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-dew-k99m3?file=/src/Navbar.js (edit: saw the answer, yeah, that's the solution)

Comment: @ChrisG yes hardcoded values were working for me as well .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the spread operator when you add your data in your state:

```
 setCount([...exercises, ...response.data]);
```

Comment: jeez man.. that worked .. how can i make you my guru (for real)

Comment: You don't want me as a guru, trust me :) pleasure to help

Comment: I believe you can be a guru when you keep learning and keep yourself up to date.

Comment: I believe you can be a guru when you keep learning and keep yourself up to date.